# Safe place to store luggage for 5 days in Sofia, Bulgaria

Tags: budget, security, luggage-storage, sofia

My family will be in Sofia, Bulgaria mid March 2016. During our stay in Sofia we are travelling to the UK for a 6 day 'side trip' but will then return to Sofia before finally travelling home to Australia. We would prefer to leave some of our luggage in Sofia for the 6 days that we will be in the UK.

Any suggestions on somewhere safe, affordable and accessible in Sofia to store luggage?

Comment: How do you travel Bulgaria - UK, flights? If so, which airport? And do you use the same point to return to Bulgaria and again to leave for Australia?

Comment: Thank you for your response. i will leave for UK from Sophia airport and return to Bulgaria from the UK via Sophia airport, which is why i prefer to store our excess bags somewhere in Sophia. WE are only 5 days in UK so want to 'lighten the load' while we travel in the UK

Answer (score 5):

Your hotel in Sofia may be willing to store your bags, especially if you are staying some nights there again on the far side of the UK journey.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [Sophia airport website](http://www.sofia-airport.bg/en/passengers/services), with its lack of information on left luggage options, combined with the fact that several other sites mention that there is not left luggage on the airport, I would say that you can't leave your luggage at the airport.
[Wikitravel has a page about Sophia](http://wikitravel.org/en/Sofia) and they do mention luggage several times on the page, including several warnings about paying extra on some kinds of public transport.

> Luggage Storage
>   If you are visiting Sofia on your way to other destinations, you can leave your luggage and tour the city for a few hours. The Central Railway Station is located right next to the Central Bus Station and offers luggage storage. It is some 10 minutes walking distance from the Lavov Most (Lions' Bridge) area and the city center. To find the Luggage department at the Railway Station look for old train placed as decoration in front of the central entrance. You can leave your luggage there for a period of maximum 5 days [4]. Also a luggage Storage office is working in the Central Bus Station, for storing luggage for 24h the price is 2Lv(July 2014) per piece.

This quote is from Wikitravel, see link above, and from that I would say the maximum time you can leave your luggage is 5 days, which might be a bit short for your needs.

That likely leaves you the traditional option if you will have been a guest in a hotel in Sophia before you head off to England. Contact your host and ask if he is willing to hold your luggage for you and what he will charge.

There might be the option of 'self storage' but I do not expect that kind of places to have an English language option, a quick online search does show that their might be options.

Comment: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/881/wikitravel-vs-wikivoyage-whats-going-to-be-the-difference

Answer (score 1):

Since the beginning of 2019, there is a new place where you can store your luggage at reasonable prices.

Its called Lockers Sofia and it is located right in front of the Serdica Metro station west exit.

The address is 121 Knyaz Boris I str.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can find luggage lockers at a place called GIFTED Sofia at 24 Ivan Denkoglu Str, working every day 10:30-13:00 and 14:00-19:30